# Regular Expression select all between <table *****> html tag

Tags: regex

Iam looking to way to find and replace multiple occurances of opening `<table >` tag using regex

tag have different patterns between <> and need to select only characters within opening tag - not between

`<table i need to select this> i dont want select this one </table>`

no language specified - i need to replace whole content opening table tag to  `<table class="table-responsive">` in sql file

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Why is there HTML in an SQL file?

Comment: it was products export from PrestaShop where person who put the product description didn't know how to make bootstrap tables

Comment: @JonathonReinhart .. [unless you know what you are going to do.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/1020526)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one-off replacement, regex will be fine. As long as there are not `>` inside the attributes of the opening tag, you can use this to select opening tags:

```
<table[^>]*>
```